# Collect change log of submodules for reporting in CI process

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm looking for a way to collect the log messages of the last "set" of commits which includes both my commits and any submodules.

I am using gitlab-ci and I have a single project that includes 4 sub modules.  When a submodule is updated it will trigger a build of the main project, and a notification will be posted on slack.

I'm using the `$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE` variable to post message content to slack, however, this will only pick up changes on my main project - not on sub modules.

In the build process I call:

```
git submodule sync
git submodule update --init --recursive --remote --force
```

to update my subs.

What I'd really like to do is be able to implement the following pseudo code:

```
foreach submodule
    collect current_git_sha
    if current_git_sha != HEAD
        collect log messages between current SHA and HEAD
    end if

    update submodule
end foreach
```

This way I can report out a message similar to:

- SubModule3: Updated some stuff

to slack.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my own question (once again).  The script I ended up using is available here:

https://gist.github.com/jeeftor/e7a07f10a38be1b7fa20e41fae88a4bc

And wrote a post about it here:
https://medium.com/@Jeef/creating-a-git-submodule-change-log-for-ci-db60c90f821c